# How to dynamically get a variable name

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

```
#!/bin/bash
year="${1:0:4}";month="${1:4:2}";day="${1:6:2}"

element=('Wood' 'Fire' 'Earth' 'Metal' 'Water')

rat=(05021924 23021925 24011936 10021937 10021948 28011949 28011960 14021961 15021972 02021973 02021984 19021985 19021996 06021997 07022008 25012009 25012020 11022021 11022032 30012033)

pig=(04021935 23011936 22011947 09021948 08021959 27011960 27011971 14021972 13021983 01021984 31011995 18021996 18022007 06022008 05022019 24012020 23012031 10022032 10022043 29012044)

Scounter=0
Ecounter=1

for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )) #10 is the number of date RANGES
do
        echo $i
#done

#echo "start of year"
#Make sure that the base value for Month and Day is base 10 and not base 8. Base 8 is a number starting with 0.
    sDay=${rat[$Scounter]:0:2};sMonth=${rat[$Scounter]:2:2};sYear=${rat[$Scounter]:4:4}
#echo "end of year"
    eDay=${rat[$Ecounter]:0:2};eMonth=${rat[$Ecounter]:2:2};eYear=${rat[$Ecounter]:4:4}

#10base conversion
#month=$((10#$month))
#day=$((10#$day))
#sMonth=$((10#$sMonth))
#sDay=$((10#$sDay))
#eMonth=$((10#$eMonth))
#eDay=$((10#$eDay))

    if [[ $year -eq $sYear && $month -ge $sMonth && $day -ge $sDay ||  $year -eq $eYear && $month -le $eMonth && $day -le $eDay ]]
    then
        if [[ $i -gt 4 ]]
        then
            echo "${element[$((i-5))]} rat"
        else
            echo "${element[$i]} rat"
        fi
        fi

    Scounter=$((Scounter+2))
    Ecounter=$((Ecounter+2))
done
```

I am trying to replace the "rat" in sDay,sMonth,sYear ,etc. with a variable that will point to the array rat or pig. I have tried using substitution by putting

```
sDay=${$rat[$Scounter]:0:2};
```

But I get a substitution error

By the way I'm working on a Chinese Zodiac script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for indirection:

```
$ rat=(05021924 23021925 24011936 10021937 10021948 28011949 28011960 14021961 15021972 02021973 02021984 19021985 19021996 06021997 07022008 25012009 25012020 11022021 11022032 30012033)
$ y="rat[1]"; echo "${!y}"
23021925
$ y="rat[1]"; echo "${!y:0:2}"
23
```

Using the above as part of a loop:

```
for x in rat pig
do
    for i in 0 1
    do
        y="$x[$i]"
        echo "$x $i ${!y}"
    done
done
```

Which produces the output:

```
rat 0 05021924
rat 1 23021925
pig 0 04021935
pig 1 23011936
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> **${parameter}**
>   The value of parameter is substituted.  The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter
>   is followed by a character which is not to be interpreted as part of its name.  The parameter is a shell parameter as described above PARAMETERS) or
>     an array reference (Arrays).
>
> **If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it
>   introduces a level of variable indirection.**  Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather  than the  value  of  parameter
>   itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this
>   are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. 
>   The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order
>   to introduce indirection.  [Emphasis added.]